# Move cursor to first row after while loop ResultSet

Tags: java, cursor, resultset

If I have to loop two times after each other using `while(rs.next())` for different reasons through the same `ResultSet`, what can I do so that the `ResultSet` doesn't close automatically and to prevent the 'ResultSet is closed Exception'? I tried using `resultset.first()` to move the cursor back to the first row after the first loop but this error fired even on this statement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your driver used.

Some driver are not able to reset a `ResultSet`. In this case you will get an `Exception` when calling `first()`.

You can check in the `Statement` with a call to `getResultSetType()` if your driver supports scrolling in a `ResultSet`.

If possible try to do your two things in one iteration as you never know if you can iterate a second time over a `ResultSet`.

Comment: I did the two things in one iteration to be safe. At least I could separate them! I am really finding problems with looping over result sets! Thanks for your help :)