# how to reset the result set to the first row after looping through a while loop

Tags: java, resultset

My code has two loops, my outer loop should loop through all the rows of the inner loop for the first row of outer loop, and the for the second row of the outer loop, it should loop through all the rows of the inner row.

```
int y1,y2;
float t = 0,s1,s2;

while(rm.next())
{
    int currentCol = 0;

    cellNumber = new jxl.write.Number (currentCol++, currentRow, index, integerFormat);
    index++;
    sheet.addCell ( cellNumber );

    cellLabel = new Label(currentCol++, currentRow, rs.getString("Name"));
    sheet.addCell ( cellLabel );


    y1 = rm.getInt("Year");

    System.out.println("Year 1: " +y1);


    cellNumber = new jxl.write.Number (currentCol++, currentRow, y1 , integerFormat);
    sheet.addCell ( cellNumber );



    s1 = rm.getFloat("Total_Price");
    System.out.println("S1: "+s1);

    while (rs.next())
    {
        y2 = rs.getInt("Year");
        System.out.println("Year 2: " +y2);

        s2 = rs.getFloat("Total_Price");
        System.out.println("S2: " +s2);

        if(y1==y2)
        {
            t = s1+s2;    
            System.out.println("Toatl Sales:" +t);

            cellNumber = new jxl.write.Number (currentCol++, currentRow, t , priceformat);
            sheet.addCell ( cellNumber );

        }


    } 
    int a = rs.getFetchDirection();
    System.out.println("Direction: " +a);

    rs.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_REVERSE);


    cellNumber = new jxl.write.Number (currentCol++, currentRow, s1 , priceformat);
    sheet.addCell ( cellNumber );




    currentRow++;

}
```

Comment: May or may not be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17450766/499922

Answer (score 19):

Use this:

```
resultSet.beforeFirst()
```

From docs:

> Throws:
>   SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method is
>   called on a closed result set or the result set type is
>   TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Comment: I am getting the following error, 

Aug 07, 2015 10:00:40 AM tsidb.SalesUI AnuualSalesCustButtonActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect cursor type

Comment: Do I need to the set the FetchDirection?

Comment: I may need to set the direction of the resultset. and set it to the first row?

Comment: I can't understand what you ask.

Comment: I want to reset the resultset, so that it starts again from the first row for the inner loop.

Comment: so, use beforeFisrt()

Comment: But that is not working in my case and giving me an error

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
resultSet.beforeFirst();
```

But you have to create the Statement this way:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

So that it is traversable and not one direction only.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
rm.beforeFirst()
```

[Official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst()):

> Moves the cursor to the front of this ResultSet object, just before the first row. This method has no effect if the result set contains no rows.

Comment: Thank you,But I am getting the following error when I try this.

Comment: Aug 07, 2015 10:00:40 AM tsidb.SalesUI AnuualSalesCustButtonActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect cursor type

Comment: How are you getting the data after you do `beforeFirst()` you need to use `.next()` otherwise use the `.first()` method instead.

Comment: I am using rs.next() to get the data. Its the while condition of my inner loop.

Comment: Are you using `beforeFirst()` on `rs` or `rm`?

Comment: I am using beforeFirst() on rs.