# How to fix 'Invalid Cursor SQL Exception' on SqlRowSet.Next() in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

After getting SqlRowSet object from H2-database, before retrieving data from the rows with `SqlRowSet.getDouble();`  I call `SqlRowSet.next();`

I've tried doing `while(SqlRowSet.next()){}`  but this shouldn't be needed as I always only have 1 row in the data .

```
public SqlRowSet findBySkuSize(String sku, String size) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("SELECT * from PRODUCT_DIMENSIONS where SKU = '" + sku + "' and SIZE = '" + size + "'");
}
```

the above method populates the SqlRowSet object (in the debugger i can see that there is 1 row shown in the image below.

```
        if(CountRows(dimensionResults) < 1) 
        {

        }
        else 
        {
            dimensionResults.next();
            someObject.objectSetterMethod(dimensionResults.getDouble("DEPTH"));

        }
```

The above code is what throws an InvalidCursorException
The stack trace is too long to paste I guess but this is the error message

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor position
at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.next(CachedRowSetImpl.java:1460)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet.next(ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet.java:697)
... 67 more

org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: Invalid cursor position; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor position
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet.next(ResultSetWrappingSqlRowSet.java:700)
at com.footlocker.commerce.shipping.service.FreightCalculationService.UpdateProductDimensions(FreightCalculationService.java:72)
at com.footlocker.commerce.shipping.service.FreightCalculationService.UpdateProductList(FreightCalculationService.java:50)
at com.footlocker.commerce.shipping.service.FreightCalculationService.ProcessFreightCalculationRequest(FreightCalculationService.java:41)
at com.footlocker.commerce.shipping.controller.FreightController.Test(FreightController.java:34)
```

[image: Debugger]

For some reason it's telling me my cursorPosition is at 2? should it start at 0? and how can it be 2 if I only have 1 Row.

Edit: I was able to change the cursor position in the debuger menu from 2 to 0 and dimensionResults.next(); worked.. So why is it that when I instantiate the object it starts at cursor position 2? Im royally confused as to why Java has to be so complicated compared to C# and finding resources to make sense of everything is difficult as well lol.

Comment: What does `CountRows` do ? Chances are that this method brings you to the end of the resultset. In that case you may want to call `beforeFirst()` to go back to the initial position of the resultset.

Comment: Wow I didn't even think of that! I guess im so used to not having to do it in such a way. I guess I was thinking that when I passed the object to a Method that it would pass a copy and whatever happened within the method to that Object wouldn't reflect.  Thank you so much, you should make that the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your `CountRows`  method brings you to the end of the resultset.

In that case you may want to call `beforeFirst()` to go back to the initial position of the resultset.

cf. [how to reset the result set to the first row after looping through a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880940/how-to-reset-the-result-set-to-the-first-row-after-looping-through-a-while-loop)

Also your position `2` is where you are after the resulset has been browsed, this is the "after last" position, the same one where you would be after calling `afterLast()`.

Finally, you may want to have a look at the following question :
[How do I get the size of a java.sql.ResultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset)

Comment: Thank you! I simply added your suggestion of rows.beforeFirst(); before returning to the calling method.